# Are there C functions or macros specifically designed to compile 1 to 1 with assembly instructions for bit manipulations in a cross-platform manner?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, x86-64

I've got a project involving emulation (If you look at my post history, you'll see how far I've come!) and I'm looking to do pseudo-binary-translation using C and playing with the optimizers and/or compilers to use C code that compiles my switch statement contents to a single assembly instruction, primarily for very standard instructions such as `mov`s, `add`, `SR` and other simple bit manipulations and arithmetic instructions. I'm hoping to do this for ARM and x86-64 at the same time, writing as little of it in both assemblies as possible.

If the thing I'm describing doesn't exist, then I wonder if there's some sort of "assembly language" that I can use to write my code and then compile that assembly into x86-64 and ARM.

Comment: A C compiler fulfils that last condition :) ... A major problem I see is that for arithmetics, machine instructions make good use of the CPU's interal flags. These are not exposed to C, you have to fully emulate them.

Comment: @Jongware would you suggest I simply forgo my efforts with writing the instructions in C and just go for JIT binary translation? (basically a C switch statement calling GOTO labels in an assembly file that have instructions mapped 1-to-1)

Comment: I downvoted your question: it is incredibly hard to understand what you really want to do and what you are really asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clearly answer this part:

> ...  then I wonder if there's some sort of "assembly language" that I can
>   use to write my code and then compile that assembly into x86-64 and
>   ARM.

That's exactly what [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) is targetting.

> The LLVM representation aims to be light-weight and low-level while
>   being expressive, typed, and extensible at the same time. It aims to
>   be a “universal IR” of sorts, by being at a low enough level that
>   high-level ideas may be cleanly mapped to it (similar to how
>   microprocessors are “universal IR’s”, allowing many source languages
>   to be mapped to them).

For [example](http://llvm.org/releases/2.6/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html):

You can represent this C function

```
int mul_add(int x, int y, int z) {
  return x * y + z;
}
```

with this LLVM IR

```
define i32 @mul_add(i32 %x, i32 %y, i32 %z) {
entry:
  %tmp = mul i32 %x, %y
  %tmp2 = add i32 %tmp, %z
  ret i32 %tmp2
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to emit machine code at run time, you need some [Just In Time translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library. You might consider [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit) ...

You could also (on Linux) generate some C code in some file, fork a compilation of that file into a shared object, then [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ing that `.so` plugin...

As I commented: cross-platform assembly does not exist and cannot exist (because systems have different [instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) and [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions): consider instead generating C code, or perhaps [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) code.

If you are writing some [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) (and that includes many [emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)), consider also [threaded code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) techniques and [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) generation.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in JIT compilation, I'm basically asking to write cross-platform assembly, with an emphasis on the assembly, not the cross-platform. I want to have control over the instructions being executed so as to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: cross-platform assembly does not exist and cannot exist: consider instead generating C code, or perhaps [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) code.

Comment: Your last comment is definitely the answer to my question, whether you knew it or not :) And I know see the merit of your original answer. If you could expand the original a bit further, perhaps with a (very brief) example, I'd love to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. As for an example of LLVM IR, please read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

To say it in a pointy fashion, the "assembly language" you're talking about is ... C.

That's because a lot of C expressions have direct mappings to single assembly instructions even on different platforms. The following is partially-hypothetical but it shows some of the instructions a certain C expression may evaluate to on x86, ARM or SPARC (choosing those three because those are the ones I know best):

```
    C code         x86 asm                   ARM asm          SPARC asm

    {              enter                     push lr          save %fp, ..., %sp
    }              leave                     pop pc           restore
    a += b;        add %ebx, %eax            add R0, R1       add %l0, %l1, %l0
    a = b + c;     lea (%ebx, %ecx), %eax    add R0, R1, R2   add %l2, %l1, %l0
    a = 0;         xor %eax, %eax            mov R0, #0       clr %l0
    a++;           inc %eax                  add R0, #1       inc %l0
    a--;           dec %eax                  sub R0, #1       dec %l0
    *ptr++;        inc (%eax)                -                -
    a = ~b;        mov %ebx, %eax; not %eax  mvn R0, R1       not %l1, %l0
    ptr = &a;      lea a, %eax               ldr R0, =a       set a, %l0
    a = b[c];      mov (%ebx, %ecx), %eax    ldr R0, [R1+R2]  ld [%l1+%l2], %l0
    (void)func();  call func                 blx func         call func
    if (a)         test %eax, %eax; jnz      tst R0, R0; bnz  tst %l0; bnz
```

Of course not everything you can write as one line of C code will transform to a single assembly instruction. It also depends strongly on the instruction set if certain multi-term operations can be "flattened" to a single multi-operand assembly instruction or require a sequence of "more primitive" instructions.

C compilers have, for a long time, done "intermediate representation" before the final convert-to-assembly; the step is similar to that done these days in hardware by x86 CPUs to "compile" the x86 assembly into lower-level micro-ops that the chip's actual execution units will process. That the intermediate layer got codified / documented as has happened for LLVM IR is not that new either ... since e.g. Java Bytecode or Forth conceptually fits that schema.

I'd go for C ... and look at the assembly output. It's not unlikely to be as-compact-as-can-be already, and on platforms where the corresponding "compound" operation is available, not unlikely to be more compact than LLVM IR (say, on a cpu with fused-multiply-add, the example auselen gave will go down to a single instruction, from three in LLVM IR).