# Linux: executing code that is loaded to memory manually

Tags: c, linux

I'm expermenting with function pointers on Linux and trying to execute this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int myfun() 
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    char data[500];
    memcpy(data, myfun, sizeof(data));
    int (*fun_pointer)() = (void*)data;
    printf("%d\n", fun_pointer());

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it segfaults on `fun_pointer()` call.  I suspect that it is connected with some memory flags, but I don't found information about it.

Could you explain why this code segfaults? Don't see to the fixed `data` array size, it is ok and copying without calling the function is successfull.

**UPD**: Finally I've found that the memory segment should be marked as executable using [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) system call called with `PROT_EXEC` flag. Moreover the memory segment should be returned by [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) function as stated in the POSIX specification.
There is the same code that uses allocated by `mmap` memory with `PROT_EXEC` flag (and works):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int myfun() 
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    size_t size = (char*)main - (char*)myfun;
    char *data = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    memcpy(data, myfun, size);

    int (*fun_pointer)() = (void*)data;
    printf("%d\n", fun_pointer());

    munmap(data, size);
    return 0;
}
```

This example should be complied with `-fPIC` gcc option to ensure that the code in functions is position-independent.

Comment: Almost certainly same error as:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7432634/168175

Comment: Could you perhaps explain some reason why you would it expect it not to segfault? It seems obvious to me that if you try to execute a random pointer that doesn't point into code, it will segfault.

Comment: The pointer points to copy of code of `myfun` because I copied this code to the `data` array.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)  then fix those warnings.   The posted code emits a whole string of warnings.

Comment: I have used similar code and that has made my program work - almost.  I ported it to c++, I can edit variables and return them in the function, but I cannot execute other functions from the "myfun" function.  they result in a seg fault.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 5):

Several problems there:

- Your `data` array stays in [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment), not in [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment).
- The [address relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) is not handled.
- The code size is not known, just guessed.

Comment: I thought about the second and the third problems, and think that in this toy example these problems should not affect. The difference between data and code segment is what I would like to understand. If I replace stack array to allocated by `malloc` the result is the same. So I want to find out is there a way in Linux to mark memory segment as "code", but not "data" during run-time.

Comment: @a-rodin; There is a way to mark memory segment as code at run time, but  surely not the way you are trying.

Comment: I think I solved all of these three problems in the question update. 

The only problem is that I'm not sure that the functions in the executable have the same order as they have in the source file, and I didn't found any documentation that ensures it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Diask's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489875/841108) you probably want to use some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques (to generate executable code in memory), and you should be sure that the memory zone containing the code is executable (see [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) and the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit); often the call stack is not executable for security reasons). You could use [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) (quickly emitting slow machine code), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (able to slowly emit fast optimized machine code). You could also emit some C code in some temporary file `/tmp/emittedcode.c`, fork a compilation command `gcc -Wall -O -fPIC -shared /tmp/emittedcode.c -o /tmp/emittedcode.so` then [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that shared object `/tmp/emittedcode.so` and use [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to find function pointers by their name there.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33809944/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25484560/841108), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880788/841108), [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/290799/40065) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303123/40065) answers. Read about [trampoline code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29), [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), and [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) & [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Of course, copying code from one zone to another usually don't work (it has to be [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) to make that work, or you need your own [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) machinery, a bit like a [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) does).

Answer (score 0):

It's because this line is wrong:

`memcpy(data, myfun, sizeof(data));`

You are copying the code (compiled) of the function instead of the address of the function.

myfun and &myfun will have the same adress, so to do your memcpy operation, you will have to use a function pointer and then copy from its address.

Example:

```
int (*p)(); 
p = myfun; 
memcpy(data, &p, sizeof(data));
```

Comment: Yes, it has fixed address, and this address should point to copy of `myfun` code. It is not a real life example, I'm just trying to figure out why can't I execute arbitrary code that the program put to the memory by itself.